# Identify points in a shapefile that have no other point within x km with QGIS

Tags: qgis, clustering, spatial-query, map-point

This is probably a naive question but I am struggling as a new user to QGIS.

I have a very large shapefile (275,000 points, but can break this into about 10 subregions if necessary for faster processing).

I want to identify all points that have no other point within 200 metres and then code each of those points with the value "unique" in a field of the file.

For all the other points that are part of local clusters I then want to code those as "clustered".

Having achieved that, I want to then select just one for each cluster on a random basis to retain in the data set, discarding the others.

Currently I am failing to achieve step 1 so any assistance would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try a self join using the *NNJoin* plugin in QGIS.

For each feature of the input layer it will find the closest feature (excluding itself in case of a self join) and include the distance and all the attributes of the closest feature in the generated dataset.  It would take some time for your dataset (I tried with a point dataset with about 175000 features, and that takes some minutes...).

Answer (score 10):

You can use Vector > Analysis Tools > Distance Matrix, and a join to achieve what you ask.

I will use [qgis sample data](http://qgis.org/downloads/data/) airport's layer to exemplify. This is a small dataset so I'm not sure how it will go with a 275000 points shapefile.

**1. Create a distance matrix using your layer as both destination and target.**

Don't forget to tick "Use only the nearest (k) target points" and set it to 1.

[image]

**2. Open the CSV with add delimited text layer**

Choose "Comma" as a delimiter, and set the geometry definition as no Geometry

[image]

**3. Create a join in the original layer with the newly created table**

[image]

**4. Use Field calculator to populate a field with the desired values**

Because of the join, we now have access to the distance table values from within the airports table of attributes, therefore it quite fairly easy to create a new field and populate it with "clustered" and "unique" values depending on the distance matrix values. because of my example data I have used the value 1200000 (1200 km), you should adapt it to your case (200).

[image]

In the end your layer should have a new field called point_type with different values according to the minimum distance to the nearest point.

[image]

Comment: That looks like an elegant solution. However I have one complication. I know there are some points that have IDENTICAL locations (these result from name synonyms during original data capture). In one case I identified 3 on the same point. I think your solution assumes (sensibly) that all points are uniquely located. Is there some obvious way I can screen my coverage to eliminate same-location points first?

Comment: @LeighBettenay If this answer addresses your original question then I think you should accept (green tick) it, to reward the answerers effort, and research/pose your additional requirement as a new question.  +1 for a great first question!

Comment: @PolyGeo Sorry I'm brand new to this forum and don't know the protocol. Happy to "green tick" a wonderful answer but sadly don't know how!!

Comment: Just click the gray tick mark below the voting of the question (to-left corner of the question). Thanks